# Visual studio 2003 solutions to Visual Studio 2013 solutions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2003, crystal-reports-2005

My question is about the different versions of Visual Studio and an effective way to update the web applications or websites that were created in visual studio 2003 to visual studio 2010 all to visual studio 2013.  Most of the solution files on the web server for the various applications or websites have not been updated since 204. But some of the .aspx.vb files have been updated in 2012.  Not sure if there is a missing .sln file or that the files were all updated manually using notepad or something?  I need to update the content of several of these projects and not sure where to begin. Looking for the most effective way to update these files.  Anyone with experience transitioning from different versions of Visual Studio working with visual basic may have these same questions. Some of these include crystal reports from visual studio 2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you opened the `.sln` file in VS2013?  I know when I was transitioning projects from VS2008 to VS2013 it prompted me to convert them when I tried to open it in VS2013.  When and if there were any issues it showed you what didn't match up and what might be obsolete.  Might be a good starting point if you haven't already tired.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I have many projects that I need to update and found out that they were updating the code inside the project in notepad and not using the .sln file.  Not sure how that is going to effect the project when I open it in 2013. I am thinking I have my work cut out for me! Any suggestions on updating crystal report files to something else?

Comment: There a reason why they are not using visual studios?  Make life a lot easier than coding in notepad.  I would hold any new development on the project you intend to upgrade till you can update them individually and upload the new updated version(if at all possible).  As far as suggestions for crystal reports, I don't have any experience dealing them, so couldn't recommend anything.